# Selenium - how to continue with url list after hitting a offline website?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

may I ask please with some assistance on the following task I'm trying to complete. Im trying to use Selenium to automatically check a list of urls and do a set of click actions on each of them, if the website is offline I would like to go to the next urls on the list and do the same click actions.

Bellow is the code that I have achieved so far, however it doesn't work:

```
from selenium import webdriver ## importing webdriver
import time ## importing waiting time fuctions
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException ## importing the timeout fuctions
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

## Setting the Timeout timer in seconds
MAX_TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 60
## Getting url from list "url"
urlsList = ['urlone','urltwo', 'urlthree', 'urlfour']
## Getting list of urls
for s in urlsList:
    urls = str(s)
    ## loop with timeout exception
    try:
        ## Activinting the Timeout fuctions
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(MAX_TIMEOUT_SECONDS)
        driver.get(urls)
        ## Clicking on tab
        systemTab = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/ul[1]/li[3]/a')
        systemTab.click()
        ## Clicking on Bottom
        buttonRaul = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/ul[2]/li[4]/a')
        buttonRaul.click()
        ## Clicking on confirmation
        buttomGoo = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/button')
        buttomGoo.click()
        time.sleep(5) ## Wait 5 seconds
    except TimeoutException:
        continue

driver.quit()
```

I tried using timeout as form to determinate if a website is offline/not responding after 60 seconds, however when the I run the code, the code online work until it hits a off-line website and stops there.

Comment: You said its not working, what is the error its throwing?

Comment: Does it throw an exception? If not, are you sure that the program is terminated and not hanged? BTW, you can use `pass` instead of `continue` since there are no further lines of code and you don't care about the error.

Comment: @pmadhu I have posted a the full message as an Answer bellow.

Comment: @CodingOtaku I have posted a the full message as an Answer bellow.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to reply this question in java as I am not much familiar with Python.
When you run the test offline mode, we can use the loadingFailed() to get the logs from browser **i.e – net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED** and then you can proceed to next URL.

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.devtools*;

    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    devTools =  ((ChromeDriver)driver).getDevTools();
    driver.get("https://www.homepage.com");
    devTools.createSession();
    devTools.addListener(loadingFailed(), loadingFailed ->
   {
       System.out.println(loadingFailed.getErrorText());
       Assert.assertEquals(loadingFailed.getErrorText(), "net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED");
   });
```

Comment: Thank you Amit Kumar Santra, If I don't manage to resolve it on python I will try your approach.

Answer (score -1):

Im pretty new to Selenium and python, The first url runs as it should be, however my second url is currently offline, The second url open the window and after 10-20seconds the following message shows and the code stop running:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sweatynerd/Desktop/smtautomation.py", line 19, in <module>
    driver.get(urls)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.107)
```

Thank for your help